# How to Unmount Shared folder

Tags: shared-folders, unmount

I have used `sudo mount.cifs -o username=(windows username) //(windows sharefoder IP addres)/(Windows Share folder name) /Ubuntu Share folder path` to access to Windows share folder. but I cant un-mount the share folder. My problem is "how can I Un-mount the share folder?" and "If I shutdown the PC without un-mounting Share folder will it be any harm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two questions here, to unmount a CIFS folder, use the following command

```
sudo umount -a -t cifs -l
```

And whether it's any harm to shutdown your linux PC without unmounting first, there shouldn't be. Unless you are writing a file to the shared folder at the same time.

Comment: +1 it wasn't worked but after following the help I have solved the problrm. -1 is no need. but how ever Thank you verymuch @James Wong for the help

Comment: :) cheers! you are welcome to post new questions should you need help with anything else!